# How can I get the Emoji code

Tags: android, emoji

like the title, I want to get the emoji code from TextView.getText();
Such as: I input a emoji smell which code is \ue415, then I use Toast to show the value (TextView.getText()), but it show the emoji image. What I want to get is the code "\ue415". I have a low English level, maybe my statement is not clear. I hope anyone can help me. Thanks for everyone.

Comment: the `\u` code is an escape sequence, you have to escape the escape sequence `\\u` to show it literally.

Comment: I have another question, how can I show the emoji in code. I write the code:Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "\ue415", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  but it shows nothing just space. And I get the code from [link](http://www.easyapns.com/category/just-for-fun), maybe the code is wrong?

Comment: See the answer below.

Answer (score -1):

you can use the below urls to implement emojis in you app

https://github.com/crowdint/emojimenu

http://www.emoji-cheat-sheet.com/